# cPanel Like File Manager

Tags: php, open-source, cpanel

I'm going to build a web hosting control panel using PHP and I want to integrate file manager like that one in cPanel. and for sure it will be great if it's free and opensource...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the HotScripts archive?

http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/